# wrong number of arguments in netbans / glassfish

Tags: netbeans, jersey, glassfish

I'm getting a very hard to trace error in glassfish 5.

This error is thrown *sometimes* when a request is made. Sometimes because I can do one of the followings to fix it (depends on the day and temperature?): restart Netbeans or re build the app, sometimes re-running also fix the issue.

As far I can see, it has something to do with glassfish / json / Jersey.

But I do not see any of my code in the stack trace so it is really hard to debug.

Where should I start?

Why is this happening and fixing by itslef on restarting?

```
Info:   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email!='NULL' AND `email`='juan@' AND `password`='dasasdassda'
Info:   SELECT * FROM `acl_master` WHERE id='0'
Severe:   Generating incomplete JSON
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.dgp.main.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.dgp.main.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.GetFromGetter.internalGetValue(GetFromGetter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.GetValueCommand.getValue(GetValueCommand.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.ReflectionPropagation.getValue(ReflectionPropagation.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.PropertyModel.getValue(PropertyModel.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.serializeRoot(Marshaller.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.marshall(Marshaller.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.toJson(JsonBinding.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.writeTo(JsonBindingProvider.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Things I'm using:

```
<artifactId>jersey-json</
<version>1.17</version>

<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
```

Comment: Try using Jackson instead of the default JSONB provider.

Comment: as far as I know we are using org.codehaus.jackson

Comment: No, you can see in the stack trace `JsonBindingProvider`. This means [JSON-B](http://json-b.net) is being used. As of Glassfish 5, this became the default provider, where as Glassfish 4, MOXy was the default. To use Jackson, you need to explicitly configure it.

Comment: Add the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency to your project (in provided scope, as the server should already have it) and register the `JacksonFeature` with the application. This is how you can use Jackson (2.x)

Comment: Other error appear when I add that dependency org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default...

Comment: Yeah I don't know what that is. I never use Glassfish.

Comment: Did you put the scope as `provided` when you added the dependency?

Comment: I've tried and the same. Is it mandatory to use Jackson, can't I just fix this error?

Comment: My point was to see if JSON-B provider was the cause of the error. That's why I said _try_ Jackson.

Comment: any other ideas to debug? I'm stuck in here, sometimes it works sometimes it does not. Really annoying

Comment: Seeing this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` are you sure the argument that pass to the sql already correct and or the return from the sql is already correct?

Comment: @SukmaWardana yeah I mean, the thing sometimes crash, and after restarting several times it works. The same is happening to me in production.

Comment: Did you ever get Jackson to work?

Comment: @user1532587 Hi, I know that it is an old question but I have the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @user1532587 Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: I also have same problem. After I removed all logs which has a lot of files (total size 117mb), problem is fixed. Logs defaults location is `glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Glassfish 5, wich ships jax-rs 2, so you should use Jersey 2.x dependency. Try  upgrading Jersey to 2.x version with provided scope.